# Efficient C code to find the column index of maximum number in each matrix row

Tags: c

I have written a C code to find the column index of maximum number (absolute max) in each row of a nxn matrix. However, there is a condition! If the column index of max number in the current row is the same as one of the previous rows, the program should skip that index and find the next max in that row.

My code works fine but performance is the main issue. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful so far in parallelize the code using OpenMP due to the dependencies. I really appreciate if you can help improve the performance of my code. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main ( unsigned long int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    int n = 3;      
    //double A[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; //output: ind_col[1,..,3] = 2,1,0  max_val[1,..,3] = 3,5,7
    double A[9] = {1,3,2,4,6,5,7,8,9}; //output: ind_col[1,..,3] = 1,2,0    max_val[1,..,3] = 3,5,7

    /* ind_col is 1xn array that contains the column index of abs. max number for each row */
    int *ind_col = NULL; 
    ind_col = (int*) calloc(n,sizeof(int)); 


    /* max_val is 1xn array that contains the abs. max number for each row */
    double *max_val = NULL;  
    max_val = (double*) calloc(n,sizeof(double)); 

    int i,j,k,rep = 0;      

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){       
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {         

            if ( (fabs(A[i*n+j]) < max_val[i]) ) continue;  // if a new max is found, do...                      

            for(k=0; k<i; k++) if (ind_col[k] == j) rep = 1; // check if the same column index was not previously used

            if (rep != 1) {    // if this is a new column index save it              
                max_val[i] = fabs(A[i*n+j]);              
                ind_col[i] = j;
            }

            rep = 0;
        }   
    }       

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("ind_col[%i] = %i , val = %f\n", i, ind_col[i], A[i*n+ind_col[i]]);}            

}
```

Comment: if `n` is smaller than 64(or 32) you could use a bitmask for the exclusion. When larger, you could use an array of bitmasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bitmask to mark the numbers of the used columns:

[you could also use a plain indicator array of chars or ints]

---

```
#define ZBITS (CHAR_BIT*sizeof zzz[0])

#define ZTEST(z) (zzz[z/ZBITS] & (1u<< (z%ZBITS)))
#define ZSET(z) zzz[z/ZBITS] |= (1u<< (z%ZBITS))

// size of A is nxn

/* ind_col is 1xn array that contains the column index of abs. max number for each row */
int *ind_col ; 
ind_col = calloc(n,sizeof *ind_col);    


/* max_val is 1xn array that contains the abs. max number for each row */
double *max_val ;  
unsigned *zzz;

max_val = calloc(n,sizeof  *max_val);
zzz = calloc(1+n/ZBITS, sizeof *zzz);               

int i,j;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){ 
  for(j=0; j<n; j++) { 
    double zabs;

    zabs = fabs(A[i*n+j]) ;
    if ( zabs < max_val[i]) continue;  // no new max is found
    if (ZTEST(j)) continue; // check if the same column index was previously used

    ZSET(j); // close the door ...
    max_val[i] = zabs;             
    ind_col[i] = j;
    }

  }

free(zzz);

#undef ZBITS
#undef ZTEST
#undef ZSET
```

---

UPDATE(2):

*improved?* version using a *mark* array for the exclusion:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned *ihaveaname(double *A,unsigned n)
{

unsigned *ind_col ;
double *max_val ;
unsigned *mark;
unsigned irow,jcol;

ind_col = calloc(n,sizeof *ind_col);
max_val = calloc(n,sizeof  *max_val);
mark = calloc(n, sizeof *mark);

for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) { ind_col[jcol] = n; } // sentinel
for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) { mark[jcol] = n; } // sentinel
for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) { max_val[jcol] = 0.0; }

for(irow=0; irow<n; irow++){
  for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) {
    double zabs;

    zabs = fabs(A[irow*n+jcol]) ;
    if (zabs < max_val[irow]) continue;  // no new max is found
    if (mark[jcol] < irow) { // check if the same column index was used by a previous row
                // fprintf(stderr,"[Skip col%u row%u]", jcol,irow);
                continue;
                }
    if (jcol > 0) { //undo previous submax
                unsigned ocol;
                ocol = ind_col[irow] ;
                if (ocol <jcol) {
                        mark[ocol] = n; // reset sentinel ...
                        // fprintf(stderr,"[Undo ocol%u]", ocol);
                        }
                }

    // fprintf(stderr,"[Mark col%u <- row%u]", jcol,irow);
    mark[jcol] = irow; // mark our row index in here ...

    max_val[irow] = zabs;
    ind_col[irow] = jcol;
    }

    // fprintf(stderr,"Max[%u] = %f\n", irow,max_val[irow]);
  }
free(mark);
free(max_val);
return ind_col;
}

int main(void)
{
unsigned uu, *uuu;

double array[9]={
        1,2,3,
        2,3,1,
        3,1,2};

uuu = ihaveaname(array, 3);

for (uu=0;uu < 3;uu++){
        printf("%u:=%u\n", uu, uuu[uu]);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it did not work. ind_col[0,..,n]=(0,1,...,n) all the time.

Comment: I could not test it, because the code in your question is not complete and compilable   & testable. So, there could be bug in my answer.

Comment: Wait: I have to **unset** the bit (from the previous max) it if a maximum is found for the second time. BRB

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also edited your code so that it can be tested. Correct output should be 2,1,0 in this case.

Comment: I'll update the answer with an (improved?) version.

Comment: Your improved code is producing wrong output. I will fix yours and will update my original question to make it testable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>



unsigned *Find_Pivot(double *A,unsigned n)
{

unsigned *ind_col ;
unsigned *mark;
unsigned irow,jcol;

ind_col = calloc(n,sizeof *ind_col);
mark = calloc(n, sizeof *mark);

for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) { ind_col[jcol] = n; } // sentinel
for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) { mark[jcol] = n; } // sentinel

double max = 0;
double zabs = 0;

for(irow=0; irow<n; irow++){   
  max = 0;
  for(jcol=0; jcol<n; jcol++) {         
    zabs = fabs(A[irow*n+jcol]) ;
    if (zabs < max) continue;  // no new max is found
    if (mark[jcol] < irow)  continue;// check if the same column index was used by a previous row

    if (jcol > 0) {          //undo previous submax        
        unsigned ocol = ind_col[irow] ;
        if (ocol <jcol) mark[ocol] = n; // reset sentinel ...                           
    }

    mark[jcol] = irow; // mark our row index in here ...    
    max = zabs;
    ind_col[irow] = jcol;
  }
}

free(mark);
return ind_col;

}



int main ( unsigned long int argc, char *argv[] )
{


unsigned *ind_col;

int n = 3;
double A[9] = {6,3,2,9,8,8,10,8,9};


ind_col = Find_Pivot(A, n);

int i;
for (i=0;i < n;i++) printf("%i:=%i\n", i, ind_col[i]);

return 0;


}
```